# How to refresh a page on button press in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating food ordering mobile application using Flutter. Every thing is working as expected but I am stuck in one point. I want to update the cart page, my page contains the icon buttons for updating and deleting the cart item in cart list. Button press is updating the cart in server as per expectation but I am stuck to update the UI for user. It is very important to update UI on successful server response to notify the user that your cart has been modified. I want to update this page without leaving this page for better user experience.  I've attached my code here. I want to refresh the UI after server response.
Please help me out.
Here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
class FoodOrderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodOrderPageState createState() => _FoodOrderPageState();
}

class _FoodOrderPageState extends State<FoodOrderPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              color: Color(0xFF3a3737),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Item Carts",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF3a3737),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 18),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          /*actions: <Widget>[
            CartIconWithBadge(),
          ],*/
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    "Your Food Cart",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Color(0xFF3a3a3b),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                CartList(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                PromoCodeWidget(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TotalCalculationWidget(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    "Payment Method",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Color(0xFF3a3a3b),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                PaymentMethodWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class CartList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String uri = API_URL+'getcart';
  Future<List<CartModel>> fetchCart() async {
    var data = {'email': GLOBAL_EMAIL};
    var response = await http.post(uri, body: json.encode(data));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {      
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<CartModel> listOfCart = items.map<CartModel>((json) {
        return CartModel.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();
      return listOfCart;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<CartModel>>(
      future: fetchCart(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        );}
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: snapshot.data
              .map((data) => CartItem(productName: data.menu_name,
            productPrice: data.menu_price.toString() ,
            productCartQuantity: data.menu_qty.toString(),
            menuID: data.menu_id,
            restaID: data.rest_id,
          )
          ).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  String productName;
  String productPrice;
  String productImage;
  String productCartQuantity;
  String menuID;
  String restaID;

  CartItem({
    Key key,
    @required this.productName,
    @required this.productPrice,
    @required this.productImage,
    @required this.productCartQuantity,
    @required this.menuID,
    @required this.restaID,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Future <void> addcart(String uEmail, String m_id, String m_name, String m_price, String qty, String r_id) async {
    var url = API_URL+ 'addcart';
    var data = {'email': uEmail, 'menu_name': m_name, 'menu_id': m_id, 'menu_price': m_price, 'qty': qty, 'resta_id': r_id};
    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg:message['message'],
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
////////// HERE I WANT TO REFRESH OR RECREATE THE WHOLE PAGE. SO THE UI GET UPDATED AS PER SERVER DATABASE.//////////////////// 
    }
    else{
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg:message['message'],
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }
  }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color(0xFFfae3e2).withOpacity(0.3),
          spreadRadius: 1,
          blurRadius: 1,
          offset: Offset(0, 1),
        ),
      ]),
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "$productName",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Color(0xFF3a3a3b),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "₹ $productPrice",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Color(0xFF3a3a3b),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        var p = double.parse(productPrice)/double.parse(productCartQuantity);
                        addcart(GLOBAL_EMAIL, menuID, productName, "-"+p.toString(), '-1', restaID);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      iconSize: 20,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        var p = double.parse(productPrice)/double.parse(productCartQuantity);
                        addcart(GLOBAL_EMAIL, menuID, productName, p.toString(), '1', restaID);
                        CartList().createElement().rebuild();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      iconSize: 20,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        deletecart(GLOBAL_EMAIL, menuID);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                      color: Color(0xFFfd2c2c),
                      iconSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),               
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want UI be rebuild - you have to write `setState()`. In `setState()` you must set variable which is used in UI.

For example:

```
if(response.statusCode==200){
    setState(() {
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    });

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg:message['message'],
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe to update UI you called `SetState(() {})` and your class must be StatefulWidget. So yeah put every variable or object that u want to update inside SetState should work.

> Basically what SetState do is Notify the framework that the internal
> state of this object has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onPressed() functionality within setState()

example:

```
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                           setState(() {
                                   deletecart(GLOBAL_EMAIL, menuID);
                            });                        
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                      color: Color(0xFFfd2c2c),
                      iconSize: 20,
                    ),
```

Comment: I'm getting this message -  The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'CartItem'.

Comment: you are using a stateless widget here, which means you cannot change the state of the app on runtime

Comment: any alternate way to achieve my object.

Comment: make your stateless widget to stateful